# Javascript Ajax data inside PHP function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have an Ajax call to create a new Quiz, with a link to the edit page of the quiz (using *Laravel*)

Now I have inside my JavaScript a PHP function, which therefor has a JavaScript variable again.

How is the variable `data.id` inserted inside the php `asset`  function?

```
$('#newQuiz').click(function () {
    var quizName = $('#quiz-name').val();
    var url = "quizzes/store";
    var token = '{{ csrf_token() }}';

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            'name': quizName,
            '_token': token
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('.quiz-table > tbody').append(
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td>' + data.id + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + data.name + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><a href="{{ asset("quizzes/".+data.id+."/questions") }}">Edit Quiz</a></button>' + '</td>' +
                    '<td>' + '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Play Quiz</button>' + '</td>' +
                    '</tr>'
            );

            $('#quiz-name').val('');
        }
    });
});
```

This rule for clarification `{{ asset("quizzes/".+data.id+."/questions") }}`

Comment: You haven't actually posted any PHP, only what looks like some Twig placeholders. In any case, you can't use PHP on JavaScript like this because PHP runs only server-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the variable data.id inserted inside the php asset function?

You can't. PHP runs on the server, you can't set the value of a PHP variable via Javascript - the opposite is true though.

Comment: @Drown he could do another ajax call though, I suspect since `data.id` is being returned by success, it was already in php form first.